# How can I close Visual Studio's dockable windows with my keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, dockable-windows

It's kind of annoying to have to use my mouse to close the windows that appear when when summoned by my keyboard e.g. I find usages of an object by hitting Shift+F12, or any of the other dockable windows that appear for various other reasons.

Ideally these would close when I hit escape, but this does nothing. Alt+F4 wants to close the entire visual studio.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to close these windows?

To be clear, this is the kind of window I'm referring to: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio), you can use the following:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> - `Window.Close` (window must have focus)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> - `Window.CloseDocumentWindow` to close the current tab

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but these don't seem to do it. I've updated my question with an image of the window I'm referring to for clarity. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I just opened up a Find Results window, undocked it from where I usually leave it, gave it focus then hit SHIFT-ESCAPE and it folded away nicely. Understand "worksforme" isn't really a useful response though sorry.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In this context "worksforme" is indeed a useful response because I know that it *should* work for me. Now I just need to track down why and then how to resolve. Do you use ReSharper by any chance? I do and it might be interfereing with my keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I don't use ReSharper at all, no - I keep trying but the boss won't spring for it! Might be worth remapping the shortcut though, if ReSharper may have messed with it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears @inksmithy has answered the question, even though it doesn't work for me. I reckon it's because I'm using ReSharper and he isn't.

For what it's worth, I just discovered Ctrl + Shift + F4 works for me.

I've decided to mark @inksmithy's answer as correct but if that doesn't work for you try my one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Focus to docked window (e.g. [Ctrl]+[g] for immediate window)
2. Press context menu key (at the right side of the space key)
3. Press the key to hide that window, indicated by _ in the contextmenu
   (depends on your language)

Answer (score 0):

"Shift + Esc" closes the docked window, only if it is pinned and control is on the docked window. I use to pin all the dock windows.